# Should I create two table to store specific information of an object?

Tags: database, database-design

I have some table:

- Course: contain info about course, one course **`has many`** topics.
- Topic: contain info about topic, one topic **`belongs to`** one course and one topic **`has many`** questions.
- Question: contain info about question, one question **`belongs to`** one topic.
- GeneralExam: Contain info about the exam of a course, one general exam **`belongs to`** one course.
- GeneralQuestion: Contain set questions of General Exam.

This is columns of two table:

- GeneralExam: name, description, semester, duration, user_id, course_id, used (boolean), number_question
- GeneralQuestion: general_exam_id, question_id

The questions will be get for GeneralExam is random. It means I will get random questions depend on specific number of question of each topic.

Now I want to know specific information of an general exam, like the number of questions of each topic in course which was made a general exam. Currently, I think I will create a new table to store that info, something like:

- New table: general_exam_id, topic_id, number_question

But I don't know if this is the best way to do it, or maybe in this case, has other ways or patterns to solve. Because If I create that New table, when I make a change in GeneralExam table(ex: change set questions), I will need to update 3 table: GeneralExam, GeneralQuestion, New table. I don't sure it is the good way.

So I want to ask, should I create new table to store that information (number of questions of each topic in course of a general exam),

Or should I need to make some changes in table GeneralQuestion for store info of general exam better, and what changes I should do? Thanks for any suggestions and advices.

Comment: Perhaps you can load all exam info to GeneralExam table. Exam is the final output of all the other info. Course -> Topic -> Question -> Exam. You wouldn't really need another new table. One can access GeneralExam table to join and query to get all the info about the exam. (Questions, Topics covered, Course it belongs to)

Comment: @bonCodigo Thanks for suggest, but I don't understand what you mean `"Each exam number and which course."`? It means i should move the course_id from GeneralExam to GeneralQuestion?

Comment: @bonCodigo are you mean my General Question table now will look like: `GeneralQuestion: general_exam_id, course_id, topic_id, question_id`?

Comment: @bonCodigo can you make clearer, 3 parents and child are what tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are trying to say, that is not required to create a new extra table. You want to manage your schema efficiently with mimimal touches to tables.

*Design Rules:*

One should not confuse the numbered topics in a particular course book to Topic table's ID numbers. Course doesn't necessarily have to be belonged to an Exam. It's the Exam who must belong to a Course. You have gotten your design so far correct. I assume you are storing all Questions for an Exam in GeneralQuestion table which acts like sort of a question bank of past Exams (including the schedule Exam in the near future which only gives access to the Exam moderators).

Makes more sense to rename your GeneralQuestions table into ExamsQuestions. With this bank your design makes two virtual question types: Exam questions from the bank and questions from Question table where Exam questions are referencing to your Question table. So that gives your the required referencial key to Exam question bank. In my opinion it is a **history** table. It seems like, your final table that you are not sure should ideally be just a **stored query** providing real time data.

Main question : Are you planning to store each past/scheduled-future Exam's questions? You say Yes. Hence,

**Date** becomes very crucial column in your Exam table according to the design I have provided. You need both Date & Course ID in Exam table.

Following is how I would suggest the table schema.

- **Reference on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79a01/5)**

*tblCourse*

ID, Course

```
ID  NAME
b105    biology 1st year
c323    chemistry 1st year
e120    english 1st year
m122    maths 1st year
m250    maths 2nd year
p302    physics 3rd year
```

*tblTopic* : Although ID is indexing, the CID is what recognizes the Topic's Parent (the Course)

ID, CID, Topic

```
ID  CID     NAME
t1  m122    Algebra
t2  m122    Probability
t3  e120    Essay Writing
t4  p302    Optics
t5  b105    liver system
t6  b105    neural system
t7  p302    mechanics
```

*tblQuestion* : Although ID is indexing, the TID is what recognizes the Question's Parent (the topic)

ID, TID, Question

tblExam : Although ID is indexing, the CID is what recognizes the Question's Parent (the course)

```
ID, CID, Exam, Date

ID  TID     QUESTION
q1  t2  x
q10 t7  p
q11 t4  n
q12 t6  i
q13 t7  r
q14 t6  k
q2  t1  y
q3  t1  z
q4  t2  a
q5  t2  v
q6  t6  s
q7  t6  h
q8  t1  l
q9  t2  g
```

tblExamsQuestions : Foreign Keys : Exam ID, Question ID

ID, QID

```
ID  CID     EXAM    DATE
e1  b105    1st Year Biology Main Stream    June, 08 2012
e2  m122    1st Year Maths Elective     December, 20 2011
e3  b105    1st Year Biology Main Stream    February, 10 2012
```

Application:
Somebody wants to get last year's Exam Questions for 1st Year Maths Course. How do you query that? If Exam ID is are on auto increment then it's very hard to know what which id is what exam. So here you could be able to search questiosn for a particular course exam only with course id and date the exam held. That should do the job -> Unless same course exams held multiple times on the same day. Then you can save your data by Time as well. You can remove Date, Time as long as you change your Exam table design to query by Exam ID where the ID is a proper exam ID not just 1, 2, 3, ...

Course ID = m122
Date = Last Year/Month/Date

These are the most logical/important details which will work as a **COMPOSITE SEARCH KEY** you need to find the Exam ID from Exam table and use that in ExamsQuestions bank to pull the Exam questions.

```
select * from question
where id in (
select eq.qid from examsquestions eq 
inner join exam e 
on e.id = eq.id
where e.date = '2011-12-20'
and e.cid = 'm122');

ID  TID     QUESTION
q1  t2  x
q5  t2  v
q7  t6  h
```

By the way since you are choosing questions randomly for an Exam - I would be so worried that if I have to take that Exam. Because the risk of getting all questions from one topic is pretty wide. Anyway that's a side issue which I hope you have a unbiased yet *FAIR* mechanism to generate Exam from all topics for a course ;)

Let me if you have further doubts. Anyone please throw some light to improve ideas for better solutions.

*PS: Sorry for the late reply.*

Comment: Thanks you so much for taking time to make a full answer. Let I tell you something about my app. When you create an exam for a course, you can specify number of questions for each topic of that course. Ex, English course has two topics: A, B. So, when you create exam, you can specific like: 10 questions for topic A, 15 questions for topic B (so, total questions of exam is 25), so I just get random 10 question belongs to topic A in Question table, and topic B is 15 questions. Do you understand what I do? So don't worried it is wide :)

Comment: Questions can not added/removed one by one, if you want to changed, you will change set questions of that exam, not only one, so you don't worried it's not FAIR.

Comment: And after I have a General Exam, I will generate for every student an exam too. Note, General Exam != Exam. Exam for each student has a smaller set questions, but it get set questions from General Exam. Ex, General Exam has 25 questions, but maybe I only choose 20 questions for generate exams for students, and this 20 questions also be got randomize from 25 questions. I think this is FAIR, because students study in the same class, with the same teacher, so students can answers what questions belongs to course they are studied.

Comment: But I want to use that info (number of questions of each topic in a general exam/exam) to statistic. Example, I want to statistic, how many questions Student 1 select right answer for topic A, and for topic B, and statistic for Student 2,3... too.

Comment: Because I get randomize,so the number of questions of each topic in every exam maybe different. Ex, maybe student 1 got exam with: 7 questions for topic A, 13 questions for topic B, but student 2 got: 10 questions for topic A, 10 questions for topic B... With your suggest SQL, I think I will run some SQL query when I want to statistic things I need.

Answer (score 1):

If the information you want can be queried from the current data, in general you should **not** store it in another table. The reason is: every time you add/remove rows from other tables, you'd have to update this one as well. It's easy to create data inconsistencies that way.

For your example (number of questions of a given topic in an exam), you can easily retrieve that info using aggregation:

```
select q.topic_id, count(gq.question_id)
from topic t join question q          on t.id = q.topic_id
             join general_question gq on q.id = gq.question_id
where gq.general_exam_id = 10
group by q.topic_ic;
```

OTOH if the data you want to store is **not** deduceable from the rest of the data, then yes, it's better to store it where it makes sense - if it's specific to the pair `(exam, topic)`, then on a table that has those two values as its [candidate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candidate_key) (i.e. exactly the way you suggested in your question). Whether to create a new table or add those columns in an existing one (with the correct candidate key, of course), it's your choice, I don't have any arguments for or against doing so.

Comment: Thanks for giving a suggest. In my app, I need to statistic things related to number of questions of topics in a general exam. I just think if I create a new table, it will be easy for me to get number of question of a specific topics, instead of using SQL query like your answer, I will just select number_question and topic_id in new table, right? But with this approach, I will need update 3 three table If a general question change (ex, change set questions), I don't sure it is a good way.

Comment: As I said, the problem with this approach is that you'll need to keep the new table up to date whenever changes are made to the other tables. IMHO that will take more work than just figuring out the right queries for each case (for instance, every time you added a question to an exam, you'd have to also update the other table; if you forget to do that in **any** part of your program, your data will be inconsistent). But you could have other reasons to do that (caching, for instance), so it's up to you.

Comment: ahh, I forgot one thing in my question. I get questions for general exam by randomize. It's mean After I put info about general exam like name,number question for each topic,... I will get random questions. So questions of general exam will only created one time when general exam created. I don't add one by one question to general exam. And I don't allow can change one by one question in your general exam, If set questions need to be changed, the new set question will be created and replace old set questions.

Comment: Even to add random or manually selected questions, you still have the questions created under a topic and a course. So the way you populate your Exam table, doesn't really matter as long as your underlying parent data is correctly structured respecting the referencial integrities, indexing with primary keys..

Comment: So, your suggest is I don't need to create new table?